# How to dispatch actions via a timer using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux-form, react-component

I'd like to dispatch an action every second to update the display of a stateless component. My initial naive attempt involved calling `window.setInterval` in the render function, which is then called each time the component renders, starting a new timer each time.

I've considered closing over a variable that indicates whether or not the timer has already started, but that would violate the concept of a stateless component. I'm wondering what the appropriate way to accomplish this via React+Redux would be, ideally while continuing to use a stateless component.

Comment: To answer you question properly more information is needed about your application and the "stateless" component. If the representation of a component depends on some value which updates frequently this is textbook definition for state. Why you want it to be stateless ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually such operations made by using `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle hooks. If you want to do it with Redux, you should implement it within container and pass your updated values into stateless component if you need it.

For instance:

```
class SomeContainer extends Component {

    _tick = () => {
        this.props.someAction()
    }

    render() {
        return <SomeComponent reduxValue={this.props.someValueFromRedux} />
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(this._tick, 1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ someReducer }) => {
    return {
        someValueFromRedux: someReducer.someValueFromRedux
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { someAction })(SomeContainer)
```